# Temporarily using existing systemvariables?

Tags: powershell, variables, foreach

So, I'm attempting to use a simple script as template to configure multiple servers with a small `foreach` loop but what I've seen in other examples just doesn't work for me and it's about using variables that already exist.

To be more specific, here is what I'm trying to run:

```
[xml]$windows=(Get-Content P:\script\windows.xml)
foreach ($host in $windows.servers.host) {  
$host.name  
$host.user  
}
```

This doesn't work due to `$host` variable already existing and while I thought of just changing the XML I noticed it's difficult to never use any tags in an XML that doesn't already have a variable that makes sense like `hostname` `host` `computername` `user` etc.

Am I just doing something wrong or how does one go around this issue?

Comment: `$Host` is an automatic variable, use another name

Comment: Well, that is the entire point of the post, how do other people use $host successfully?  
There are so many pre-defined variables so building a coherent xml without ever using one of them is difficult.

Comment: @PatrikPersson You need to reference about_automatic_variables. Also Get-Variable will show you all that already exist so you can check that until you are familiar with them. This is not something that bothers me. Its just a variable name ... change it to something else like `$singleHost`

Comment: @PatrikPersson Not sure I understand ... who says that variable names and XML node names have to be the same? :)

Comment: Technically they don't "have" to be but it looks a lot better than adding your own tagnames and not use what is known in the IT vocabulary so it is easy to use for others.  
When I do things I build it in mind that one day I'll be gone and someone else will have to go through my scripts and understand what is going on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no clue why you get variable name conflicts but you could also pipe the nodes to the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet and use the *automatic pipeline variable* `$_`:

```
 $windows.servers.host | ForEach-Object {  
    $_.name  
    $_.user  
}
```

Comment: Interesting workaround, but it works! Never seen this being used as an alternative example but now we have a perfect scenario to describe the differences in `foreach` and `ForEach-Object` !

Comment: foreach-object iterates over each *pipeline* object whereas foreach-loop iterates over a list.